# Using awk to extract a specific text in a Makefile

Tags: awk, makefile

I have a config file with this format

```
foo=bar
fie=boo
..
..
```

and there is a Makefile, I want to extract a line of config file that have a string 'disk_size' then extract value that is assigned to the variable

this is the line I've used in Makefile

```
fallocate -l $(shell awk -F= '/disk_size/ { print $2 }' $(conf)) $@
```

but I receive this error, (the whole line was extracted.)

```
fallocate -l disk_size=268435456 disk.img
fallocate: invalid length value specified
```

the awk command work in terminal but it doesn't work in Makefile, why?

tnx

Comment: There may be reasons against this, but it's conceivable that you could just say `include $(conf)` and use `$(disk_size)` directly in the makefile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably just need to escape the `$`:

```
fallocate -l $(shell awk -F= '/disk_size/ { print $$2 }' $(conf)) $@
```

Make is trying to use the variable `$2` rather than passing the string `$2` to awk.

Comment: I have never seen `$$2` in `awk`, I doubt this is going to work.

Comment: @fedorqui `awk` is not going to see `$$2`.  Make will see `$$2` and pass `$2` to awk.

Comment: So this is a way to "escape" the `$` so that `awk` still sees `$2`. OK, nice, didn't know it!

Comment: You don't want `$(shell)` here. It is executed at the wrong time and pointless. You are *already* in shell context there. Just use `$$(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If your config file is really this format:

```
foo = bar
disk_size = 1234
```

You can directly include it in the Makefile:

```
# Include configuration file
include $(conf)

target:
    fallocate -l $(disk_size)
```

You can also use the `-` operator to ignore error of the `include` command and assign default value if there is no config file.

```
# Include configuration file
-include $(conf)

# Set default size
disk_size ?= 5678

target:
    fallocate -l $(disk_size)
```